# Why can't Talends tSOAP not connect to a .NET Webservice

Tags: .net, soap, talend

I'm using the Talend tSOAP component in order to send a soap request. If I use a Java-based test web service I receive a positive response. If I use the ASP.NET-based test service I receive a fault error message like this:

```
<s:Fault xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><s:Code><s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value><s:Subcode><s:Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</s:Value></s:Subcode></s:Code><s:Reason><s:Text xml:lang="de-DE">The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</s:Text></s:Reason></s:Fault>
```

My request message looks like:

```
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:msv3:v1\">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
  <urn:verbindungTesten>
     <clientSoftwareKennung>YAMA</clientSoftwareKennung>
  </urn:verbindungTesten>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"
```

I can't find the error and need some help.

Answer (score 0):

The .net and Java WSDL syntax can vary - to help you troubleshoot, you should have a look at each test server's WSDL and compare them to help you figure out how they differ.

I'd also recommend using the Talend component called tESBConsumer rather than tSOAP as tESBConsumer can parse the WSDL and build the SOAP request envelope for you. You'll likely have to use it in combination with tXMLMap and save the schema to your metadata, but the documentation at https://help.talend.com should help you out - you can search by component and there are examples too.